# Airflow: Long log text is in wrong order in UI

Tags: python, airflow

Using airflow v 2.7.1

We are logging very long logs that we get from another system, where there are thousands of lines, all starting with the line number. Now the logs in the UI starts with the line number 1000 for logs that are longer than that.

Previously at some point the logs were showing up fine in the UI even if they were long, but we have lost track of when, unfortunately.
Logs are stored in Azure blob storage and are fine in that place, downloading them results in correct logs, therefore we conclude the issue is with presentation of the logs only.

Is there anything we can do to fix it?
Did anyone experience the same problem?